# Volley and Retrofit are not fetching data using mobile data connection

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit, retrofit2

I am experiencing some problems when fetching data from the server using android volley. The data can be fetched when I am on WiFi but I get an error when I am on a mobile connection. I tried using retrofit but it also cannot fetch data on mobile. Any idea on what the problem can be?

Comment: Do you have an active data option for your mobile connection?

Comment: Yes. I can access other applications that require the internet using mobile connection

Comment: Are you reveiving some errors? I don't think is from your mobile connection.

Comment: I get a server error. I am using digital ocean as my server. Can it be an issue with SSH?

Comment: Post the stacktrace, please.

Comment: It would help posting your code along with any error messages you are getting.

Comment: BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404
com.android.volley.ServerError
at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)